# Join multiple strings enclosed in quotation marks with underscore

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
list = ["My Strings to be Combined" "More Strings"]
```

That I would like to turn into this:

```
new_list = ["My_Strings_to_be_Combines, More_Strings]
```

How would I best do it? I was thinking about doing something like this, but a regular expression may be better suited:

```
#select word between quotation marks 
for i in list:
new_list_elements= i[(i.index('"')+len('"')):i.index('"')]

#repalce spaces with underscore
new_list= [words.replace(' ','_') for words in my_string]
```

Comment: Use the string `.join` method. `', '.join(list_of_words)`

Comment: It is not clear if you want the resulting ```new_list``` to have just one element composed of the concatenation of the elements in ```list``` separated by a  comma and spaces replaced by underscore or a list of the previous elements with spaces replaced by underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way combining `string.join()` and `string.replace()`:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 16 2019, 19:49:22) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20181215 (Red Hat 8.2.1-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more informati
>>> 
>>> lst = ['My Strings to be Combined', 'More Strings']
>>> new_lst = [', '.join([s.replace(' ', '_') for s in lst])]
>>> new_lst
['My_Strings_to_be_Combined, More_Strings']
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your list comprehension is perfectly good; `replace` is efficient and readable.  However, you should not name a variable (`list`) to shadow an existing built-in type.
You can skip the intermediate steps and go straight to the list comprehension:

```
>>> a = ["My Strings to be Combined", "More Strings"]
>>> [s.replace(' ', '_') for s in a]
['My_Strings_to_be_Combined', 'More_Strings']
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `.replace()` to change spaces to underscores (which we save into a new list), followed by `", ".join()` the items in the list together with a comma and a space.

```
my_list = ["My Strings to be Combined","More Strings"]
new_list = []
for item in my_list:
    item = item.replace(" ", "_")
    new_list.append(item)

print(", ".join(new_list))
```

Outputs:

> My_Strings_to_be_Combined, More_Strings

Comment: Sry.  If you have a list as follows: lst = ["Cancer Sites Code" Mortality-Incidence Age-Adjusted Rate Ratio] How would you apply it if you want the new list to be: new_lst = [Cancer_Sites_Code, Mortality-Incidence, Age-Adjusted, Rate, Ratio] ? Note that lst is of length 0

Comment: @Horbaje a) `lst` is of length 1...
b) If it is all one item, the quotes should encompass everything if it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace

```
list = ["My Strings to be Combined", "More Strings"]
newList = []
for str in list:
     newList.append(str.replace(" ", "_"))
print(newList)
```

Comment: Ok, follow up question. I like the join method and the replace as well. But if you have a list as follows: `lst = ["Cancer Sites Code" Mortality-Incidence Age-Adjusted Rate Ratio]`  How would you apply it if you want the new list to be: `new_lst = [Cancer_Sites_Code, Mortality-Incidence, Age-Adjusted, Rate, Ratio]` ? Note that lst is of length 0 !

Comment: For something like that I would use a regular expression to get everything in quotes, this expression should work: `(["'])(\\?.)*?\1` @Horbaje